# How do I embed an anchor tag into a template string?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I guess my question is two parts. I need to type a prop so that it can accept a string, and anchor tag or a string *with* and anchor tag. Currently, I have it set up as follows:

```
export interface SomeProps {
   description: ReactElement | string;
```

As such, it can only accept a ReactElement **or** a string, not both.

The second part of my question is that with the way `description` is typed, I cannot do something like the following which is what I'm trying to do:

const descriptionText = `Insert some text here that has an anchor tag: <a href="www.link.com">click me</a>`

I have tried using either the `ReactElement` or `string` for `description` each by themselves, but that means that if I use `ReactElement` as the type, I can't use a string (ie: `'A text without an anchor tag'`) for the `descriptionText` and likewise if I use a string, I can't use the following `<a href="www.link.com">click me</a>` within the string as it'll just translate the entire line of code to a string (ie: `This is a text with an anchor tag <a href="www.link.com">click me</a>`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you should replace ReactElement by React.ReactNode in order to do like `<p>your text <a href="www.link.com">click me</a></p>`